# Menu on mobile triggers when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I have a div element with an image inside of it, which upon hovering over displays another div right on top of it with some clickable options. It all works perfectly on PC where you can actually hover over elements, but on phones hovering is impossible and you have to press the image for the menu to display. The problem is that if I tap on the image for the menu to display, it automatically triggers the options in the menu instead of just displaying it and requiring another tap on the options.

[How the div looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAMaD.png)

Is there a way to get over this problem with html/css and if not, is there a solution using js?

Thanks.

Comment: try to change `hover` on your CSS to `active`

Comment: Tried it, still got the same problem as before.

Comment: can you please post the CSS code

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/gdBG6FSL (switched back to hover)

Comment: SO you'r options are view and delete and they appear when div is overed; right? and on mobile when you tap on the div view or delete is activated(as "clicked").

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Answer (score 1):

ok - what you can do is:

- Wrap the options in a div an make it as `display:none` at least for mobile viewport media
- for `window.outerWidth <= 768`add a click event on the image or the div that need to be tapped to show the options and on that click event show the options wrapper div
- I don't know for sure but this could possibly work with `:active`and `:focus` css events like this `.parent:focus .optionsWrapper, .parent:active .optionsWrapper{display: block;}`
- In any case, yours as well use `display: none` instead of `opactity:0`

  Explanation
- `opacity:0` just hide the element but it's still there
- `display:none` mean that the element does not exist (in simple words)-sure you can access it by javascript but not with user direct action like click or hover